# How do I make the TotalScores unique to their Reference data in my View?

Tags: sql, database

I have a View that has a column named 'Reference' and a column named 'RateeId' and collects and computes data from another table and used SUM function to get its TotalScores. However, when I input the same RateeId but different Reference, the SUM calculates both and displays the same Scores.

This is what I have tried so far.

This is my script for my view:

```
select e.Id, b.Name, f.SiteName, e.Reference, e.Amount, e.DateTransaction, SUM(a.Score * (c.Weight / 100) * (d.Weight / 100))  as TotalScore, a.Status, a.CreatedByUserId
from prs_rate as a 
left outer join prs_ratee as b on a.RateeId = b.Id
left outer join prs_kpi as c on a.KpiId = c.Id
left outer join prs_group as d on c.GroupId = d.Id
left outer join prs_totalratee as e on a.RateeId = e.RateeId
left outer join core_vSiteInfo as f on e.SiteCatered = f.siteCode
group by b.Name, a.Status, a.CreatedByUserId, e.Reference, e.Amount, e.DateTransaction, f.SiteName, e.Id
```

This is what it returned:
[This is the View prs_vMainKPI. The result of the above script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utnRP.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please tag your DBMS, don't upload images or links, provide both sample data and expected result as tables with text in your question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Please add `order by` clause and try again...

```
select e.Id, b.Name, f.SiteName, e.Reference, e.Amount, e.DateTransaction, SUM(a.Score * (c.Weight / 100) * (d.Weight / 100))  as TotalScore, a.Status, a.CreatedByUserId
from prs_rate as a 
left outer join prs_ratee as b on a.RateeId = b.Id
left outer join prs_kpi as c on a.KpiId = c.Id
left outer join prs_group as d on c.GroupId = d.Id
left outer join prs_totalratee as e on a.RateeId = e.RateeId
left outer join core_vSiteInfo as f on e.SiteCatered = f.siteCode
group by e.Id, e.Reference, b.Name, a.Status, a.CreatedByUserId, e.Amount, e.DateTransaction, f.SiteName
order by e.Id, e.Reference
```